# Android GPS working but icon never stops blinking

Tags: android, geolocation, gps, location

I am writing an application which tracks activities using the devices GPS and Google's location service API. The GPS is working and showing the live location on a map, however the GPS icon in the toolbar is constantly flashing, as if it is still searching for a lock. Also it takes a few seconds to locate the current position which I guess could be normal?

When I use other applications such as the Nike running app, the GPS locks on very quickly with a solid icon so I know it is not the conditions or signal.

I set up the location with the following code:

```
// Create the LocationRequest object
mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
// Use high accuracy
mLocationRequest.setPriority(
        LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
// Set the update interval to 2 seconds
mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
// Set the fastest update interval to 1 second
mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL); 
mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
mLocationClient.connect();
```

Then this is the on connected code:

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
    if (servicesConnected())
    {
        mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, this);
        mCurrentLocation = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();   
    }
}
```

I then deal with location data in the onLocationChanged method. Everything seems to be working well, it's just the flashing GPS icon and the initial short delay of getting a lock.

Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: What are your intervals set too? Too low and they will have trouble getting a lock before it retries it's next location lock (causing inconsistent connections).

Comment: Ah right, thank you. Currently the update interval is set to two seconds, and the fastest interval is set to one second. I will try playing with the values and see if it helps. Thank you.

Comment: Yea, had that issue before when I was using those exact values. Had to bump my interval to, I think, 5.

Comment: @zgc7009 I have tried changing the values to a higher amount, as much as 10 seconds but still the icon is flashing, strange. Thank you for your help though!

Comment: Hi same issue here. Did you finally find a solution ? Thank to share.

Once I got a location with required accuracy I stop the fusedLocationUpdates, and expire the locationRequest. But the GPS icon is still flashing...